# References for children's names in Deadpool 2 specifically Earl

Tags: character, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool-2

There are so many movie/character references in Deadpool 2.  Vanessa and Wade are discussing names for children.  Vanessa says, "How about Earl?  No, he will end up in jail".  I was wondering if this has a character or movie reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's a reference to the TV series "**My name is Earl**" where the main character (indeed, Earl) makes a list of every bad thing and every person he has ever wronged and make efforts to fix them all to change his bad Karma, but during the seasons working at his list he commit more than one illegal choice and gets arrested several times.